# SQL Server partitioning of many-to-many tables - triggers

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Many to many tables usually have only foreign keys to related tables, like

```
EmployeeId
PositionId
```

Is it good idea to add column only for partitioning and set its value with INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE trigger from one of the related tables that has such a column?

Comment: Do you have enough employees that hold enough positions to make partitioning even useful here? What would you possibly be partitioning on?

Comment: This sounds like a very generic question to me. Do you have a specific problem you're having trouble with? In particular, what sizes are your tables? What's an example of a column you are thinking of partitioning on?